# Nested dictionary and group query in Redis

Tags: python, json, dictionary, redis

I'm using Python dictionary to store in-memory key-value pairs; I chose to use json to store k-v pair on disk. One problem is as key-value pairs are frequently updated, flushing dictionary into json files may be slow. Is there a good way to solve this problem?

I am new to redis, and it seems it's hard to convert nested dictionary into redis keys for group query. e.g., in redis, `john:2014->good, john:2015->average,` how to convert them into nested dictioary in python,

```
{"john": [{"2010":"good"},{"2015":"nice"}]}
```

A single key "john" can get all relevent info.

Truly appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a structure like this?

```
{"john": {"2010":"good", "2015":"nice"}}
```

The Redis key will be `john` and the value will be `{"2010":"good", "2015":"nice"}`